# How to get sorted results in MongoKit?

Tags: python, pylons, pymongo, mongodb

How can I perform query like: db.articles.find().sort({created_at: -1}).limit(5); in MongoKit driver?

Perhaps I'm blind, but I can't find it in [manual](http://bytebucket.org/namlook/mongokit/wiki/html/tutorial.html#query). I want to retrieve 5 last products ordered by 'created_at'. MongoKit offers to sort result list (it's more then 2000 items) and slice it. It's unaccepable, I want to sort() and limit() on database level, not python :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.articles.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(10);
```

That should work a charm. The "_id" is the database ID which basically like a primary key in the old SQL days.

Comment: Ok, this mean I was stupid. conn.test.cart.find().sort("_id", 1) - (without braces) really works. Sorry for my inattention. And how to sort with many fields? .sort().sort() ?

Comment: sort({_id:-1, title:-1})

So just add a comma between each argument. This {} bracket object notation is pretty universal, json, python, actionscipt, javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Correct MongoKit/PyMongo equivalent is

```
connection.articles.find().sort('created_at', pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(5)
```

More at [PyMongo cursor doc](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort).